# Orthogonal similarity transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can someone please show me how to diagonalize a matrix such as the one below using an orthogonal similarity transformation?
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 2 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I have been looking everywhere online to find an example of orthogonal similarity transformations but I can't find any. Am I searching for the wrong thing? Is there another name for it, because similarity transformations seem awfully close to Jordan canonical form?

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there some difference between an *orthogonal* similarity transformation and a regular similarity transformation?

Comment: [Here's](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1064229/how-to-diagonalize-this-matrix/1064245#1064245) the usual process for diagonalizing a matrix.

Comment: I wish I knew the answer to your question..I was hoping someone would explain that to me. Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: A similarity transformation of $M$ is just $P^{-1}MP$ where $P$ is invertible. An orthogonal one is when $P$ is even an orthogonal matrix. It always exists when the matrix $M$ is real and symmetric, like yours.

Comment: The eigenvalues are $1$, with eigenspace the plane $\Pi:x+y+z=0$, and $4$, with eigenspace the line $L=\Pi^\perp$ (directed by the unit vector $e_1:=(1,1,1)/\sqrt3$). Choose any orthonormal basis $(e_2,e_3)$ of $\Pi$, and the matrix $P$ whose columns are $e_1,e_2,e_3$ will do the job.