# (A−λI)x=0 and x≠0 iff det(A−λI)=0: Why [[1,1],[1,1]][[2],[3]] = [[5],[5]] ≠ 0 when det([[1,1],[1,1]]) = 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, determinant

As refered to [Why non-trivial solution only if determinant is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288308/why-non-trivial-solution-only-if-determinant-is-zero?answertab=oldest#tab-top),

I wonder why  \begin{gather} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\5 \end{bmatrix} ≠ \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix} \end{gather}
when  \begin{gather} \det \begin{pmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\end{pmatrix} = 0 ?\end{gather}
Above is conflict to the fact that "$(A−\lambda I)x=0$ has a nontrivial solution (a solution where $x\neq 0$) if and only if $\det(A−\lambda I)=0$ " to me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Because $\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$ is not an eigenvector. You cannot choose any vector and expect it to multiply to the zero vector.

Comment: @TobyMak Thank you.  Do I understand it correctly that the statement "Ax=0 where x≠0 if and only if det(A)=0" is only valid when x is an eigen vector of matrix A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant of that matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$is indeed $0$ and there is indeed a non-trivial solution for $Ax=0$ , namely $x=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$ and its multiples.

Why you get $\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$ into it, I don't know. Your computation shows that $\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$ is *not* an eigenvector, and mine shows that $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}$ is.

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a mistake while editing the post. Now I corrected it. Thank you for your kind answer. Hope you come back again and see my revised question.

Comment: @MaysaMayWittayanontawet My question still remains. What's with $\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Oh. So you mean the statement "Ax=0 where x≠0 if and only if det(A)=0" is only valid when x is an eigen vector of matrix A? Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @MaysaMayWittayanontawet no, that's not what I mean at all. For any *square* matrix $A$, $Ax=0$ has some non-$0$ solution $x$ iff $A$ is not invertible iff $\det(A)=0$. It follows from more general linear algebra facts. $A-\lambda I$ is a square matrix, hence the fact you quoted. And by definition $x$ is an eigenvector for $A$ iff $x$ is a non-$0$ solution of $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ for some $\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you a lot. So it doesn't imply Ax=0 iff A is invertible ?

Comment: @MaysaMayWittayanontawet $A$ is invertible means "$Ax=0 \implies x=0$" for square matrices. So then there are no non-trivial solutions.

Comment: Thank you. So the fact that A is invertible and x is not zero doesn't imply Ax = 0 ?

Comment: Not for all $x$ as I said, but only for a specific $x$. You can use row-reduction to find that $x$.

Comment: @TobyMak Thank you. You meant only x that is a vector whose basis are the column vectors of A?

Comment: @TobyMak And that means only an x that is an eigenvector of A?

Comment: No, since you have $Ax = 0$ and not $(A-\lambda I)x=0$.

Comment: @TobyMak How are Ax=0 and (A−λI)x=0 different?

Comment: It seems like you do not have a solid grasp on linear algebra to me. I thoroughly suggest you revise the theory and any concepts you do not understand. For any other questions you may have, please ask a separate question.

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Comment: And to answer your question, $Ax = 0$ is usually used to solve systems of equations (where all the equations are set to $0$), and $(A-\lambda I)x = 0$ comes from raising powers of matrices. Finding the eigenvectors and eigenvalues are essential to diagonalising the matrix in the form $A = PDP^{-1}$ where it can be easily manipulated with.

Comment: @TobyMak Thank you a lot for your help. I may need to revise and then post a separate question.

Comment: That's fine, no problem :)

Comment: @TobyMak I have posted a new question which is more straight forward to my confusion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3333807/which-one-is-correct-between-ax-0-land-x-neq-0-iff-deta-0-and. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, the determinant of the transformation matrix has little to do with finding the eigenvalues or eigenvectors. It is the determinant of $A - \lambda I$ that matters. Here, you apply the theorem that a homogeneous system $AX = 0$, where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, has a non-trivial solution if and only if the determinant of $A$ is $0$. Note that using 0-determinant as a criteria works for homogeneous system only. For in-homogeneous system $AX=b$, where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $b$ is not $0$, the system has a unique solution if the determinant of $A$ is not $0$. The criteria for homogeneous and in-homogeneous systems are exactly opposite.

Going back to your matrix

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \ 1 \\ 1 \ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

there is indeed no contradiction with the theorem that the homogeneous system $AX=0$ has a non-trivial solution if and only if the determinant of the $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is $0$.

In the context of eigenvalues, this is your homogeneous system:

$$(A - \lambda \cdot I)X = 0$$

$X$ is non-trivial if and only if $det(A-\lambda I)$ is $0$. You actually have two eigenvalues by solving this homogeneous system: $\lambda_1 = 0$ and $\lambda_2 = 2$.

Substituting $\lambda_1=0$ back into the homogeneous system $(A - \lambda I) X = 0$, you have

$$\begin{bmatrix} {1-0} \   1 \\ 1 \    {1-0} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$$

As long as $x_1$ is the opposite of $x_2$, this system will be true. So, $\lambda_1=0$ gives you infinitely many eigenvectors $\begin{bmatrix} t \ -t \end{bmatrix}$, i.e., $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \ -1 \end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix} -1 \ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ or scalar multiples of them.

Substituting $\lambda_2=2$ back into the homogeneous system as above, you got infinitely many eigenvectors as well $\begin{bmatrix} t \ t \end{bmatrix}$, i.e., $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ or scalar multiples.

As shown, given the transformation matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \ 1 \\ 1 \ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, the theorem for solutions of homogeneous square matrix system is not contradicted.

Comment: Thanks for editing my formulas. I am new to Math Stack Exchange. I normally typed the math formula in MS Word, saved them as pictures, then attached them to my post. However, yesterday, my computer was malfunctioning and I had to switch to a computer that did not have Microsoft Office installed on it. I was also a bit used to online class forums where people just typed the formula or described them in words and most of the time, we understood what each other meant. Thanks again for the editing to make the formulas for readability.

Comment: With regards to the plausibility of my answers, I am currently taking a Coursera specialization on mathematics of machine learning offered by Imperial College of London. That's how they taught course participants how to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Prior to this specialization, I also spent several months reviewing relevant concepts using MIT's open courseware materials. (I said "reviewing" because I graduated with a BS in mathematics years ago.)  I can give you the link to MIT's open courseware materials so that you can fact-check my answers if you want to.