# Which one is correct between "$(Ax=0)$ $\land$ $(x\neq 0)$ $\iff det(A)=0$ " and "$(Ax=0)$ $\land$ $(x\neq 0)$ $\implies det(A)=0$"?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, logic, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

As referred to [Why non-trivial solution only if determinant is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2288308/why-non-trivial-solution-only-if-determinant-is-zero?answertab=oldest#tab-top),

that says "$(A−\lambda I)x=0$ has a nontrivial solution (a solution where $x\neq 0$) if and only if $\det(A−\lambda I)=0$ "

which I assume that can imply $(Ax=0)$ $\land$ $(x\neq 0)$ $\iff \det(A)=0$ for any square matrix $A$ and vector $x$

that can further imply  $\det(A)=0 \implies (Ax=0) \land (x\neq 0)$ for any square matrix $A$ and vector $x$

But when $\begin{gather}  A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \end{gather}$ which $\det(A)=0$, it doesn't imply $(Ax=0) \land (x\neq 0)$ for any vector $x$ because there exists a vector $x = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\3 \end{bmatrix} ≠ \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix}$ but $Ax = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\5 \end{bmatrix} ≠ \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\0 \end{bmatrix} $

So I am confused and wonder if it is actually "$(Ax=0)$ $\land$ $(x\neq 0)$ $\implies det(A)=0$" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of quantifiers:

The statement is not $$\forall x \neq 0: Ax = 0 \Leftrightarrow \det A = 0$$

but rather 
$$\exists x \neq 0: Ax = 0 \Leftrightarrow \det A = 0 ~~.$$

In particular, this means that if $\det A = 0$, then there exists a vector $x \neq 0$ s.t. $Ax = 0$. Not just **any** vector; **some** vector.

In your case of $A := \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, the vector $x := \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$ is not $0$, but $Ax = 0$.

Comment: In addition to what G.Chiusole said, once your matrix has dependent columns, the correspoding map $\varphi$ with $\varphi(x) = A x$ will have a non-trivial kernel.

Comment: Oh Thank you. Are those some x that exist in $$\exists x \neq 0: Ax = 0 \Leftrightarrow \det A = 0 ~~$$ have to be the eigen-vector of $A$ ?

Comment: @MaysaMayWittayanontawet A priori they don't **have** to be, but they are. If $x \neq 0$ and $Ax = 0 = 0x$, then that is equivalent to $x$ being an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$. To be precise, $x$ has to be in the kernel of $A$.

Comment: I see. So 'they always are' ?

Comment: @MaysaMayWittayanontawet Yes, they always are. Maybe my comment was a bit convoluted.

Comment: @G.Chiusole Thank you! finally my confusion has been solved. Spent a day because of it, couldn't  get over.

Comment: @MaysaMayWittayanontawet You're welcome. If your question is answered, please mark it as such by accepting an answer (by clicking the tick to the left of the answer) such that the question does not appear in the "unanswered queue"

Comment: @G.Chiusole Done. Thank you!